# How to connect to my EC2 instance via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have an instance in AWS and I'm trying to connect to it via SSH I already try in Windows with Putty and PowerShell and I already convert the key pair to readeable format for Putty but it's not connecting to the instance the error says:

Connection Time Out

Also I already try to connect with a Linux machine but it doesn't work too

This is my instance configuration

[image]

These are my security group policy

[image]

[image]

Comment: SGs look fine. Maybe something else blocks? NACLs or you have some firewall somewhere?

Comment: You lunched instance in custom VPC i see. Public subnet correclty setup?

Comment: It's look like I have an inbound ACL associated to my subnet that is denying all traffic source 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: But it's not giving me the option to delete it

Comment: This is probably "*" (star) rule, which is default. Before that should have "100" rule. Have you modified NACLs, or use default ones?

Comment: I have the default ones

Comment: And the VPC settings? Everything set correctly for public subnet? Internet gateway, route tables?

Comment: I created another instance but with a default VPC and I could connect to that

Comment: Yes, because all subnets in default VPC are public. You must be using private subnet in your VPC or have misconfigured public one.

Comment: It seems that probably I have something wrong with my custom VPC I going to check and compare what is wrong

Comment: Thank You Marcin!

Comment: All you need in your custom vpc are, 
an internet gateway, 
a route table with a default route (0.0.0.0/0) to internet gateway, 
and the subnet of the instance is associated with that route table.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- **Security Group** permitting inbound access for port 22 (SSH) (Looks good!)
- **Network ACLs** set to default (Looks good!)
- Instance launched in **public subnet** (??)
- Linux AMI used (Ubuntu, looks good!)
- Instance has a **public IP address** (Looks good!)

The one thing that isn't clear is whether the instance was launched in a **public subnet**. This is defined as a subnet that has a Route Table pointing to an **Internet Gateway**.

If you can connect to other instances in the same subnet, then this would be configured fine. If you have not been able to connect to anything in the subnet, then **check your Route Table configuration**.

Comment: Yeah, It seems that probably I have something wrong with my custom VPC I going to check and compare what is wrong. Thank you!